# Simulate Background Task' Not Printing to Console in Simulator using SwiftUi

Tags: swift, swiftui, background-task

Based on documentation from here [Using background tasks to update your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app)

I've implemented a background task in my AppDelegate to print "Hello World - Performing background task" when app is in background. However, when I run the app in the Simulator and use the Debug menu to 'Simulate Background Fetch', nothing is printed in the console.
I am using Simulator with iOS 17.0 version. What is wrong here and why I cant simulate the background task with logging something to the console?

- "Background fetch". is checked
- Permitted background task scheduler identifiers are set

  ```
   import UIKit
   import BackgroundTasks
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       // Register background task
       BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.myapp.refresh", using: nil) { task in
           self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
       }


       return true
   }

   func scheduleAppRefresh() {
       let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.myapp.refresh")
       request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60) // Fetch no earlier than 15 minutes from now

       do {
           try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
       } catch {
           print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
       }
   }

   func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
       scheduleAppRefresh() // Schedule a new refresh task

       //background task logic here
       print("Hello World - Performing background task")

       task.expirationHandler = {

       }

       task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
   }
  ```

  }

Comment: Did you put the breakpoint after submit and then put in the line in the debugger

Comment: I have added this in the breakpoint lldb, but nothing gets logged after pressing enter and then c --- >

 e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"com.example.myapp.refresh"]

Comment: it the breakpoint located after the submit code

Comment: yes it is located after the submit code

Comment: Did you make sure you Info.plist and Capabilities are setup correctly

Comment: yes I have checked "Background fetch" and "Background processing" and in info.plist I have set Permitted background task scheduler identifier. And also I have in my plist Required background modes to "App processes data in the background"

Comment: Try using the SwiftUI way of registering a task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494254/background-task-backgroundtask-doesnt-work-in-swiftui/77494836#77494836