# Swift Background task not triggering

Tags: swift

Since some time I have tried to use background tasks in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks

But for some reason I cannot get it working. I do not use simulator but build directly to my device. Iam using SwiftUI but to get it working I have enabled `AppDelegate` to handle the background tasks like visible below.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        let taskId = "co.echonova.LemonAppIos.fetchGps"
        
        // Handler for the task. My assumption is that it will print "Task did run". Also debugger does not enter this method.
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskId, using: .main) { task in
            print("Task did run")
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        }
        
        // Check if there are pending tasks.
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests { request in
            print("\(request.count) BGTasks pending..")
        }
        
        // Schedule the task
        do {
            let newTask = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: taskId)
            newTask.earliestBeginDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(10)
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(newTask)
            print("scheduled")
        } catch {
            print("failed to schedule")
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

But for some reason the task never get executed. The terminal shows:

```
1 BGTasks pending..
scheduled
```

My expectation is that the terminal should print after ten seconds

```
1 BGTasks pending..
scheduled
Task did run
```

Any idea why this does not happen? I have tried a lot already but did not get it working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494254/background-task-backgroundtask-doesnt-work-in-swiftui/77494836#77494836

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Good one. But I have already tried that approach but also no response. The task did not get started.

Comment: Did you try running the LLDB command? BGTasks are requests/suggestions 10 seconds is quite soon and ir definitely won't run every 10 seconds.

Comment: Yeah I can imagine indeed. The 10 seconds is just for testing. In reality I like it to be around 5 minutes. I also did run the LLDB command. But no response..

Comment: Last time I tested this, when scheduling a background task, it fired in roughly 5 minutes (when charging; when on wifi; not connected to the Xcode debugger). Note, `earliestBeginDate` is only for “don’t run sooner than specified date”, not “run it at the specified date”. That’s why we have that `lldb` command, when you want to explicitly fire at a precise moment in time. See [Starting and Terminating Tasks During Development](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting-and-terminating-tasks-during-development).

Comment: Also, just to confirm: Are you doing this on a physical device? “The debug functions work only on devices.”

Comment: WWDC video [Advances in App Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707) is a decent primer/tutorial on the topic…