My BackgroundTasks code is not working in background, but works on debug
I am trying to upload a file to S3, authenticated by AWS Cognito, automatically from the background even when the app is closed.
So this is my AppDelegate Code:
import BackgroundTasks

class BackgroundTaskManager {
    static let shared = BackgroundTaskManager()
    
    private init() {}
    
    func registerBackgroundTasks() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.healthdata.upload", using: nil) { task in
            self.handleBackgroundTask(task: task as! BGProcessingTask)
        }
        print("Background tasks registered.")
    }
    
    func scheduleUploadTask() {
        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.healthdata.upload")
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600) 
        
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
            print("Successfully scheduled upload task. Next run scheduled for \(request.earliestBeginDate!).")
            
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule background task: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func handleBackgroundTask(task: BGProcessingTask) {
        print("Handling background task with identifier: \(task.identifier)")
        
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            queue.cancelAllOperations()
            print("Task with identifier \(task.identifier) is about to expire.")
        }
        
        let operation = BlockOperation {
            self.uploadData { success in
                if success {
                    print("Upload task completed successfully.")
                    task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
                } else {
                    print("Upload task failed.")
                    task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
                }
                self.scheduleUploadTask() // Schedule the next task
            }
        }
        
        queue.addOperation(operation)
    }
    
    private func uploadData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        print("Starting data upload.")
        HealthStoreManager.shared.fetchAndUploadHealthData { success in
            print("Data upload finished with success: \(success).")
            completion(success)
        }
    }
}

The app builds and installs just fine but no upload happens as expected when the device is disconnected and the app is closed. I've waited for as long as 3 hours to verify it.
Also, when I try the debug method using
e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"TASK_IDENTIFIER"]
as given in the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting-and-terminating-tasks-during-development
the file uploads, but then I stop and disconnect my device and just let it be. And for like 2 to 3 hours, there are no uploads to the specific location. I haven't waited for more than that since the task is scheduled every hour for testing (ideally I would want it once per day).
Does it mean my code is definitely working as intended because the debugger function works and uploads the file and I just have to wait over 3 hours to verify it when the device is disconnected and the app is closed? Or is there something wrong with my code itself, but that wouldn't explain how the debug function uploads the file.

SwiftUI has a different workflow for background tasks, you can give that a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494254/background-task-backgroundtask-doesnt-work-in-swiftui/77494836#77494836 the request also has a requiresNetworkConnectivity that should be set to true

@loremipsum Yes I did check that before, thanks. Wasn't sure how to implement it and it looked like I needed to changes in all my code files to implement it. Anyway, could that be a potential reason as to why my code doesn't work or is that just an alternative. Also the main question remains, since the debugger function uploads the file, does it mean the code is working as it should?

I would think you would get something after a couple of hours but it also looks like you are using health, a lot of that is encrypted and isn’t allowed to be queried in the background or when the device is locked.

To perform background uploads, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background/  You want to schedule the upload and then let the OS handle actually performing it. You likely will not have enough time in the background to perform it yourself.

(When you're running in Debug and connected to Xcode, your app generally will be allowed to run in cases where it would not be allowed in a production build. That's to assist you in debugging. It doesn't imply that it's promised.)
